# Restart required after edit of yum.config?

Tags: linux, yum

I have just updated yum.config to exclude tomcat, and I was wondering if there is anything I need to restart following this? From what I see I got the impression there is nothing to restart.

If someone could confirm or deny this that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean `yum.conf`, you are correct, at least as regards the operation of yum from the command line.  A new `yum install` or `yum update` should take your changes into account immediately.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. And sorry - I did mean yum.conf (not yum.config). If yum is set up to automatically run, this will also pull in the updated config yeah?

Comment: If it's set up to run from cron, then yes, each invocation is separate, and future ones will pull in the new config.  Forgive the gentle prompting, but I see you're fairly new around these parts.  The done thing, if you're completely happy and satisfied with an answer to a question, is to accept that answer (I seem to recall this means clicking on the tick outline).  If you're hoping for more answers here, then you're completely free to wait as long as you like; but it is expected that questioners will accept an answer eventually.  Hope it was OK to say that!